# Автокликер (бот) на C# для внешнего приложения (эмуляция клавиатуры)

Tags: c#, клавиатура, эмулятор

мне нужно для себя написать автокликер, который будет "эмулировать" нажатия на клавиатуре для выделенного (или определенного окна). Желательно на С№ (т.к. пока что нормально разбираюсь только в нем).
**Собственно я пробовал (отрывки кода) :**

```
// 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  v1)   SendKeys.Send("W"); 
//
v2)  static class KeyboardSend
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

            private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
            private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;

            public static void KeyDown(Keys vKey)
            {
                keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
            }

            public static void KeyUp(Keys vKey)
            {
                keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
            }
        }
        private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.W);
            KeyboardSend.KeyUp(Keys.W);
        }
//
```

**но все это работало только в блокноте, калькуляторе и тп, но совершенно не работает с играми(:**
также я нашел библиотеку InputSimulator но visual studio отказалась принимать любую ее версию.

*Чуть подробнее про задачу :* надо чтобы *"кнопка1"(любая кнопка на клавиатуре)* **зажималась** на 15сек./(или навсегда) , через 3сек. после начала **нажималась** *(один раз)* *"кнопка2"* , еще через 5сек. **зажималась** на 2,5сек. *"кнопка3"* и еще раз *"кнопка3"* на 2,5сек. Затем по новой. (и именно из-за одновременного нажатия кнопок идея с экранной клавиатурой и курсором не подходит)

Заранее благодарю, мне будет достаточно +_подробного объяснения как реализовать само нажатие кнопки или нормально работающей библиотеки(:
(если вам лень будет это объяснять , просто напишите мне программу с открытыми исходниками, можно даже на другом языке). ЕЩЕ раз БЛАГОДАРЮ.

Comment: вообще под такие задачи лучше использовать готовые библиотеки. Кода будет меньше, сам код будет проще, а багов и проблем будет меньше. Уверен, такие библиотеки есть.

Comment: @andrew таких библиотек нет

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer InputSimulator.

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer https://github.com/cwevers/InputSimulatorCore 1 минута поиска в гугле

Comment: @Andrew, скзаали что не получается в студию импортировать

Comment: Нл спасибо, если способ @aepot не поможет, попробую импортировать библиотеку эту

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer боюсь вас расстраивать, но если вам `SendInput` не поможет, то вам ничего не поможет, потому что все существующие библиотеки используют именно его, и [эта в том числе](https://github.com/cwevers/InputSimulatorCore/blob/master/WindowsInput/Native/NativeMethods.cs#L91). `не получается в студию импортировать` вы всему верите, что пишут в вопросах?

Comment: @aepot а зачем ему обманывать?) Ну в любом случае, чуть посже затесщю оба варианта